# How to save list of team members in asp.net to sql server database table?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, forms, webforms

I am designing a Follow up report form in asp.net  for employees to enter data in it and save the data to the database table. The form looks as below,

[image]

I know to save data until team members as they are either one selection or textbox value but I don’t know what to do about Team members. There may be up to 16 members in a team. How shall I save it in the database? Shall I create 16 different varchar fields like teammember1, teammember2, … teammember16 but that will be too much. Which asp.net control to use for this team members values? Shall I use separate textboxes for each member in team? I am really confused what to do about team members in the above form. Could anyone help me and let me know how to do it correctly.

Comment: Are you asking about how to design the table structure or how to design the UI ?

Comment: I am asking both. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Design database possible as to maintain the `1:m` and `m:1` relation ship and avoid the `m:m` relationships. And for UI if your player list is fixed then you can use the chekbosex or dropdown list or textboxes with the autocomplete. I can not write the complete code. Try doing this and in case of problem come back here.

Comment: Ok let me see what can I do

Answer (score 1):

**First Question :** how we can save team member values to database

You can use different ways.

> one way you can save this all values in a single field as comma
>   seperated.The time of retriving you can split it .
>
> Another way : Use a separate table and store one value per row, with a
>   foreign key pointing back to your table.

**Note :** The first method is a bad practice i prefer the second one

**Second Question :** Which asp control will be suitable here :

**I think it is better to use Textbox here .**

Note : **Never display 16 text boxes at first time**. just display 1 text box and after finishing the first textbox value it will dynamically create and show another textbox and so on.Untill the limit reaches.

> Or you can use a jquery popup for getting the value of team
>   players. I think it will look smarter

Comment: Bad advice to use the comma separated values to stored in database.What if he wants to query each members data in future ?

Comment: Yes @CoderofCode you are right. I may need to query members data in future.

Comment: @CoderofCode i agree with you. i  just say it is one method ,and also i had included another method too in my answer

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV the OP is new to this you should not give the bad approaches and if you are giving him that at least try to add explanation why its possible the worst mistake  anyone can made in database design.

Comment: Can anyone give me a sample code to achieve what I need?

Comment: @CoderofCode Save data in comma separated is a bad practice i have agree with that. but i think it is possible to query each member in future ? am i right ? correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes it is possible but that leads to more complicated queries and database design. Why make a mistake in first place .

Comment: @CoderofCode Why  database complication ?? take the data as a single string from the database and we can process it in server side simply.Anyway i had edited my answer and note down the method is not a good practice as per your sugection

Comment: @CoderofCode he use asp.net for creating his application . and he knows what data goes to database and what data coming from database , so in his server side he can process the data i think it is better than use complicated queries in sql.

Comment: @Javed if you are looking for 1 st method then just create varchar datatype column in your database then save all memeber names to that field as comma seperated , i mean from your server side process all memeber name add comma after each name convert it as a single string then save it to database, and at the time of retrieving just take the column value , don't worry about comma take the value in to your serverside and process the data i mean just split it using comma. if you are looking for second method then

Comment: @Javed Save the member names to another table. i mean enter each name in each row. and give a single id for all members under the team. and using that id you can take all members of a team

Comment: ok @ArunprasanthKV I will try but I would have appreciated if you could provide me with an example or sample code or webform. Anyway thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

*"I am really confused what to do about team members in the above form."*

You can do the following

**For Webform:**

Use a `gridview` control. Add `textbox` control in one of the `template fields`. You can add `edit` and `delete` `template fields` also in case you need to modify the data.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMembers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ForeColor="#333333"
    ShowFooter="True" Width="212px" OnRowDeleting="gvMembers_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Team Member">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMember" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddMore" runat="server" Text="Add More" onclick="btnAddMore_Click"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Delete" Text="Delete" />
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#102040" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

You can find code for how you can make a gridview dynamic on the net.
For rest you can use the usual controls as shown in the image posted by you.

**For Database**
Create two database table.
One for the followup report (which will not contain team members)

```
create table follow_up_performance_report
(
    report_id int primary key identity,
    report_type nvarchar (20),
    section nvarchar(30),
    leader nvarchar(30),
    head_leader nvarchar(30),
    time_to nvarchar(50)
)
```

Next one for Team Members only.

```
create table report_team_members
(
    report_member_id int primary key identity,
    report_id int constraint fk_rep_id foreign key references follow_up_performance_report(report_id),
    team_member  nvarchar(30)
)
```

When you save webform, first insert it to `follow_up_performance_report` and create a method to call table's `last report_id` and then insert the rest (team members) into table  `report_team_members`.

Hope this works for you.